# SceneManager.LoadScene("Loading Scene"); not working even when adding using Unity.Engine.SceneManagement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im writing a simple scene management script but for some reason I am getting an error that says there is no description for "LoadScene" under SceneManager. I have put using Unity.Engine.SceneManagement at the top of my script, however it is grey showing that it is not in use. Any Ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class SceneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public void OnClickNewGame()
    {
// "scenemanager does not contain a description for loadscene
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Loading Scene");
    }


}
```

Comment: Make sure You are not  referencing your class because they share the same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you named your own class to `SceneManager`, which results in an ambiguity when you call this:

```cs
SceneManager.LoadScene("Loading Scene");
```

The compiler then tries to use your `SceneManager`, resulting in a fail since you haven't defined the method `LoadScene()` in *your* SceneManager.

Either rename your class to something else, or change the call to force the compiler to use Unitys scenemanager like this:

```cs
UnityEngine.SceneManagement.LoadScene("Loading Scene");
```

Renaming your class would probably be best to avoid any other complications.

Comment: Went right over my head! Thank you!